# Crystal- Reports: Exclude a field value from running total

Tags: crystal-reports

[image]In crystal reports is how can one exclude a field value from running total. This field is not suppressed however we donot want to add its value to the sum total.

Comment: can you show sample data?

Comment: I have attached sample data, I want to exclude last column value from the sum in this case 82.18

Comment: I want to exclude a value on the basis of another suppressed column, I want that if NonDelivery  is suppressed, exclude the value 82.18 from the sum which is displayed in the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to create one more column for the calculation purpose and then place after the last column and write below formula:

```
if column="NonDelivery"
then value
else 0
```

Now take the sum of this column and then place the sum below your mail value column and supress the newly created column.

Comment: Thanks siva. I made it work by adding a column in the data set returned and binding the sum with this column